# Microsoft Graph API - Problem to access oneDrive in route '/me/drives'

Tags: javascript, node.js, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to use Microsoft Graph API to acess oneDrive folders and archives in node.js, the authentication goes fine, and returns the calendar as well, but i have used this:

```
var graph = require('@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client');
require('isomorphic-fetch');

module.exports = {
  getUserDetails: async function(accessToken) {
    const client = getAuthenticatedClient(accessToken);

    const user = await client.api('/me').get();
    return user;
  },

  // GetEventsSnippet
  getEvents: async function(accessToken) {
    const client = getAuthenticatedClient(accessToken);

    const events = await client
      .api('/me/events')
      .select('subject,organizer,start,end')
      .orderby('createdDateTime DESC')
      .get();

    return events;
  },


  getDrives: async function(accessToken) {
    const client = getAuthenticatedClient(accessToken);

    try{
      const drive = await client
            .api('/me/drive/root/children')
            .get();

      console.log(drive);
      return drive;
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }
};

function getAuthenticatedClient(accessToken) {
  // Initialize Graph client
  const client = graph.Client.init({
    // Use the provided access token to authenticate
    // requests
    authProvider: (done) => {
      done(null, accessToken);
    }
  });
  console.log(client);
  return client;
}
```

And it don't return anything... But saying that im unauthenticated

I am following this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/drive_list?view=odsp-graph-online

How can i make this work?

Comment: Have you tried the same API call with Microsoft Graph explorer or POSTMAN? I just tested it and it works for me.

Comment: Are you still looking for help here?